# TypeScript: types for variadic functions

Tags: typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open-ended function arguments with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697275/open-ended-function-arguments-with-typescript)

Is there any acceptable type signature for variadic functions? Example:

```
function sum () {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

gives me compilation error:

```
foo.ts(9,12): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697275/open-ended-function-arguments-with-typescript/12697349#12697349 - open-ended function arguments with TypeScript

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In TypeScript you can use "`...`" to achive the above pattern:

```
function sum (...numbers: number[]) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <  numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
  }
  return sum;
};
```

This should take care of your error.

Comment: I guess it doesn't support the multiple type feature?  For example, this will not compile:  foo(...item: string[] | number[])

Comment: @Lee it won't swallow `string[] | number[]`, but `(number|string)[]` is perfectly ok (although you will likely need to do some casting inside function body).

Comment: or `...numbers: Array<number | string>`

Comment: you could also make it a template function if you want to specify they're all the same: `function sum<T extends number | string>(...item: Array<T>): T`