# Typescript error with zip function in Lodash

Tags: typescript, lodash

I was wondering why Typescript complains with the following error:

```
(22,28): error TS2453: The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'string' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'number[]'.
```

when I use the zip function with the following arguments:

```
let ranges = ["0-100", "100-200", "200-300", "300-400", "400-500"];
let arrays = [[19.99, 49.99, 49.99, 49.99, 29.99, 29.99, 9.99, 29.99, 34.99, 34.99, 59.99], [149.99, 179.99, 129.99, 149.99, 129.99, 199.99, 129.99], [209.99, 249.99, 292.99, 279.99, 219.99]];

let result = _.zip(ranges, arrays);
```

However, if I use _.zipObject, the error disappears.

In case it is important, I installed the type information using `typings install lodash --save`.

**UPDATE 2**

I think `zip` doesn't like to receive arguments with different types. In this case, `ranges` is of type `string[]` and `arrays` of type `number[]`.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong. I changed the values of `arrays` to use strings, but now I get this slightly different error:

```
(24,28): error TS2453: The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'string' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string[]'.
```

Maybe there is something related to the nested arrays in the variable `arrays`?

Comment: what about explicitly specifying union type as generic parameter? `_.zip<number|string>(...)`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: No, still not working. I guess you meant to explicitly type what is the expected output for `_.zip`. I think that would be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `zip` does not like arguments of different types.  As defined here...

```
zip<T>(...arrays: List<T>[]): T[][];
```

This basically means that all of the parameters must be an array of the same type.  However, when you changed arrays to strings I suspect you had something like...

```
let ranges = ["0-100", "100-200", "200-300", "300-400", "400-500"];
let arrays = [["19.99", "49.99",...], ["149.99", ...], ...];
```

These are still not the same type.  `ranges` is a one dimensional array of strings (array of `string`) and arrays is a two dimensional array of strings (array of `string[]`).  A valid set of inputs would be something like...

```
let ranges = ["0-100", "100-200"];
let arrays = ["19.99", "49.99"];
```

Here both types are arrays of strings.  However, I suspect this is not what you want.  Is your desired output something like the following?

```
[["0-100", ["19.99", ...]], ["100-200", ["149.99", ...]], ...]
```

If so then you can simply do...

```
_.zip<any>(ranges, arrays);
```

This tells typescript to force `T` to be `any` so the function definition becomes...

```
zip(...arrays: List<any>[]): any[][];
```

Example:

```
let ranges = ["0-100", "101-200"];
let arrays = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]];
_.zip<any>(ranges, arrays);
//[ [ '0-100', [ 0, 1, 2 ] ], [ '101-200', [ 3, 4, 5 ] ] ]
```

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments, you could also do...

```
_.zip<string|number[]>(ranges, arrays);
```

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer. I was confused about the types used in the definitely typed definitions. A couple of questions: What is the `List` type in the context of `List<T>[]`? How do you read `<string|number[]>`?

Comment: @RobertSmith `<string|number[]>` - Either string or array of numbers, `<(string|number)[]>` - either array of strings or array of numbers. See [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: `List` is actually defined elsewhere in the lodash type definitions.  It is intended to be slightly more generic than arrays to include jQuery objects.  You could think of it as `<Array|jQueryObject>` except there is no common type for jQuery objects so they defined it a little differently (e.g. anything indexable with a `length` property).  The `...` is a way of saying, [allow zero or more arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697275/open-ended-function-arguments-with-typescript).  So this function can take 1, 2, 3, or however many items you want, each item needs to be a `List<T>`.

Comment: So basically it is saying, give me zero or more arrays (or jQuery objects), each of which can be cast to some common type `T`.  The actual zip implementation will receive these List objects as an array which is why it is `List<T>[]` and not `List<T>`.  It is not saying the arguments are each `List` arrays (which would be a 2-dimensional array) but rather that all of the `List` objects will be grouped into an array for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I had to read it a few times, but now it is clear what it means.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a form of `_.zip` which allows you to specify, as type parameters, the types contained within the arrays.

`zip<T1, T2>(arrays1: List<T1>, arrays2: List<T2>): Array<[T1 | undefined, T2 | undefined]>;`

so you would be able to write

```
_.zip<string, number[]>(ranges, arrays);
```

This would return `Array<[string | undefined, number[] | undefined]>` and would allow you to avoid using `any` (which defeats the purpose of using TypeScript)