# Typescript generic base class that defines a base callback type

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to create a generic base event class:

```
class BaseEvent<T extends { (args?: any[]): void }> {
    addEventListener(listener: T): { (): void } {
        return () => { };
    }
}
```

That I can extend to specify the restrict the parameters of the callback:

```
class ExtraSpecialEvent
    extends BaseEvent<{ (foo: string): void }> {

}
```

But I cant seem to figure out the syntax.  [Here is a playground demonstrating my problem](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20BaseEvent%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20(args%3F%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20addEventListener(listener%3A%20T)%3A%20%7B%20()%3A%20void%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SpecialEvent%0D%0A%20%20%20%20extends%20BaseEvent%3C%7B%20()%3A%20void%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ExtraSpecialEvent%0D%0A%20%20%20%20extends%20BaseEvent%3C%7B%20(foo%3A%20string)%3A%20void%20%7D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D).

Any idea how to accomplish this?

---- UPDATE ----

As answered below by @murat-k, my generic is asking for an array...  While this is what my question asks, its not what I *meant*.  My intention was to allow 0 or more `any` args.  The solution to my problem was to change the generic to:

```
class BaseEvent<T extends { (...args: any[]): void }> {
    addEventListener(listener: T): { (): void } {
        return () => { };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `args` as an array type. You have to pass it as a array e.g.

```
class ExtraSpecialEvent
    extends BaseEvent<{ (foo: string[]): void }> {

}
```

Comment: Ok, yes, you are correct.  I will mark this as the answer...  Though it turns out I was asking the question wrong...  I really wanted the ability to specify 0 or more any args...  This answer sent me down the right path.

Comment: @Lucas For that you could use the `...` rest parameter. See here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697275/open-ended-function-arguments-with-typescript