# How to check arguments passed to a function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, parameters

I'm writing in Typescript and then compiling my TS code into JS.
I'm stuck here, because I don't know how to resolve the error mentioned below:

> TypeScript Error on Line:2 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'arguments'

My TS Code:

```
1        function testSomething() {
2            var paramsPassed = arguments;
3            console.log("Params are : ", paramsPassed);
4            return arguments.length;
5        }
6
7        const result = testSomething("this", "is", "a", "demo");
8        console.log("Output I want: " , result);
```

I don't know from where to import this or how else to accomplish my task.

Comment: whats is `arguments` supposed to be?

Comment: **arguments** in this scenario, returns an *array of all the arguments* passed to the function'. You can run my code block in your browser console ...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments keyword will only work inside JavaScript file and not in TypeScript file.

Change the function as below,

```
function testSomething(... arguments: string[])
```

Please check the ref link below,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697349/11914056

Comment: cannot use 'arguments' this way, use "...inputs: any[]"