# How can I access 'arguments' in a TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a single argument, which I will call `options`. I prefer not using the `options` style (I rather like named arguments) but this is a requirement for now. A type for the items inside the `options` object is supplied per the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

```js
const doThing = async ({
  query = null
}: {
  query?: string;
}) => {
  var options = Array.from(arguments)[0]
};
```

This fails with:

`Cannot find name 'arguments'.ts(2304)`

I don't understand this, as `arguments` should exist in all JS functions.

How can I use `arguments` in a Typescript function?`

### What I am trying to do:

- have a single `options` argument
- enforce typing and have default values on the data inside
- be able to access that `options` argument by a name.

Comment: I think you want to do `(...arguments) =>  { var options = Array.from(arguments)[0] }`

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697349/457268

Comment: @k0pernikus That would remove all the typings. Additionally the function would no longer take a single `options` argument, which is a requirement of the question.

Comment: You still can type for the `(...argument: T[]) => `. If you have a fixed tuple of different types, it may make sense to type for that instead ` ([foo, bar]: [number, string]) => {...}`. Though I am a bit unsure of what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @k0pernikus I just want to be able to have a single argument, enforce typing on the data inside, and be able to access that argument by a name. I'm just learning about TypeScript tuples now, could you please write a full answer in the same form as the question?

Comment: Not related to typescript - arrow functions do not have an arguments objects. It is not clear from your example what are you trying to do..

Comment: @AlekseyL.Thanks, I didn't know that. What I am trying to do: have a single argument, enforce typing on the data inside, and be able to access that argument by a name.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Confirmed via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: So just `const doThing = (options: { query?: string }) => { ... }` Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Can you do that and provide a default value for `query`?

Comment: No, same as in plain JS. But you can do it when desctructuring options. Or you can provide default value for whole `options` parameter

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the comments, arrow functions don't have the reserved `arguments` variable.

But you can still have type safety, a single named argument *and* default values if you just split up these requirements into different statements. That will also make the code much easier to read and understand:

```js
interface Options {
    query: string | null;
}

const defaultOptions: Options = {
    query: null,
}

const doThing = async (options: Partial<Options>) => {
    const completeOptions: Options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
};
```

Additionally the `Options` interface actually specifies the strucure that you need inside the function body this way.

Also you can now pass a partial set of options without having to specify all properties literally twice inline, where the value level of the signature -- `{ query = null }` -- specified the default values before, and the type level -- `{ query?: string; }` -- specified *both* the types and the fact that option keys are optional. The optional part is now done with the `Partial` type instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by the using overloads of the function. This will allow:

1. To have a function with a single parameter.
2. Inform the different types to the type system.
3. Change the function behavior depending on the type you received. (This violate the OOP principle of Single responsibility, but let's go back to your question...)

So your function overloads would look something like this:

```
function doThingFunc(arg: { query: string, somthingElse?: string }): void;
function doThingFunc(arg: string): void
function doThingFunc(arg: any): void {
  if (typeof arg === 'object') {
    console.log(arg.query);
  }
  if (typeof arg === 'string') {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
const doThing = doThingFunc;


doThing('some query');
doThing({ query: 'some query', somthingElse: 'something else' });
```

Of course, with this implementation you lose the *this* binding when used inside an object that arrow functions provide out of the box. More details here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html